# MVC - Best way to add outer element

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been developing with MVC for a few years and this is a nagging issue I have encountered several times.  I do not like any of the ways I have handled this in the past so I thought I would ask here.

Let's say I have a series of nested DIVs on my view:

```
<div id="outer">

  <div id="inner1">

    <div id="inner2">


    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

At runtime I want to add another element, a DIV or anchor, inside of the outer div but have it contain the inner DIVs.

```
<div id="outer">

  <div id="newone">

     <div id="inner1">

       <div id="inner2">


       </div>

     </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

How would you recommend handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine this would have more to do with JavaScript than with the server-side code.  And since ASP.NET MVC comes with jQuery, you may as well make use of [the `wrap()` function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).  Something like this:

```
$('#inner1').wrap('<div id="newone"></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks David, I hadn't thought of that approach.  I was coming at it from the Razor side.  In my model will be the data that tells me if I need to wrap it.  I can definitely do that with your suggestion.